# What "something" is the Mandarin referring to?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, shang-chi-legend-of-the-ten-rings

In *Shang-Chi and The Legend of The Ten Rings* (2021), the Mandarin speaks about Ying Li:

> MANDARIN: She gave up everything so we could be together. And so did I.
> After all those years, I finally found **something** worth growing old for.

What "something" is the Mandarin referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "something" Xu Wenwu is referring to is his love for Ying Li and their children. It was for their sake that he gave up the power of the Ten Rings, including his immortality, causing him to grow old.